# How to get Microsoft vc++ runtime package in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

In my SDK i didn't find that reference.i installed windows 8 release preview.Working on Bingmaps sample try to add reference like right click on solution-->Add Reference-->Windows-->Extensions in that i didn't find Microsoft VC++ Runtime Package.please tell me .Where to get this dll?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Bing Maps SDK?  That should add the C++ runtimes into the environment for you.

Comment: i installed that bing map SDK.but i didn't find any c++ in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below article for more details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx